# How to abort a thread without Abort()?

Tags: c#

In my Windows form application, I get a video stream from camera, and I want to display it in a picturebox of my form.

I have a list box that contains the cameras, I drag and drop in the picture box and it launches the function to retrieve the stream of the camera, it works, however when I set a new camera on the picture box, I mean that if the `cam.IsAlive` we cut all the thread. It never shuts down I also tried with a Task.

My `lauchCam`:

```
private void launchCam(PictureBox box, int numCam, CancellationToken ts)
        {
            

            VideoCapture video = new VideoCapture();

            video.Open(listCam[numCam].Url);
            using (Mat image = new Mat())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (!video.Read(image))
                    {
                        Cv2.WaitKey();
                    }
                    if (listCam[numCam].Url != "")
                    {
                        Bitmap bitmap = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(image);
                        box.Image = bitmap;
                    }

                    if (Cv2.WaitKey(1) >= 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

My drag and drop function:

```
   private void pictureBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            int numero = 0;
            numero = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

            var data = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);
            

            if (data != null)
            {

                string rtsp = listCam[numero].Url;


                if (camera1 == null)
                {
                    camera1 = new Task(() => launchCam(pictureBox1, numero, ts));
                    camera1.Start();
                    activ.Insert(0, 1);

                }
                else
                {
                    if (!camera1.IsCanceled)
                    {

                        
                        try
                        {
                            ts.Cancel();
                        }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(OperationCanceledException)} thrown with message: {oce.Message}");
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            ts.Dispose();
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Task {0} status is now {1}", camera1.Id, camera1.Status);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        camera1 = new Task(() => launchCam(pictureBox1, numero,ts));
                        camera1.Start();
                    }

                }
            }
            else { Console.WriteLine("ERROR"); }
        }
```

Comment: ``` var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken ct = ts.Token;```

Comment: What is `launchCam`? Is that the loop which actually gets frames from the camera and displays them? If so, sounds like that's where you want to put the calls to `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`

Comment: Yes `lauchCam` is the loop where i gets frames, ok i will try !

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include that, we might be able to help. Right now, we don't have much to go on. The general approach is to pass your `CancellationToken` to `launchCam`, and then regularly call `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. Note that there appear to be some problems in the code you did post, e.g. you'll start a new `Task` every time that code is called (do you want multiple threads all executing `launchCam` at the same time?), and you never properly wait for `camera1` to complete after cancelling it

Comment: I have put lauchCam in answer below

Comment: Don't do that. It's not an answer. [edit] it into your question, as I asked

Comment: this is the first time I post..

Comment: Which is why it's important to read what people say to you. I asked you clearly to [edit] that information into your question, and you still ignored that and posted it as an answer.

Comment: Right, inside your `while(true)` loop, call `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`. That will throw an `OperationCanceledException` if the `CancellationToken` has been cancelled

Comment: like this ? 
```
while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }
                    catch(OperationCanceledException oce)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("" + oce);
                    }
```

Comment: You don't want to swallow the `OperationCanceledException`, otherwise your loop won't exit. You need to let the exception bubble up past the loop

Comment: Ok ty, I will try to code, I will come back to you

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with the posted code.

1. Inside the loop you should be calling `ts.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` to actually cancel the loop.
2. A TaskCancellationTokenSource can only be used once. You should cancel the existing object and then create a new one for the next call.
3. `box.Image = bitmap;` is run from a background thread. This is just not allowed. Only the UI thread should update the UI. You should ask the UI thread to do this instead, for example by calling [Control.BeginInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)
4. When the task is canceled, awaiting, waiting, or getting the result of the task will throw OperationCanceledException, not `ts.Cancel();`. But you are never awaiting or otherwise dealing with the result of the `launchCam`, and this is a problem. If the method throws an exception, you would never know. I would suggest awaiting the task and show a message box or otherwise log any exceptions other than OperationCanceledException.

I might suggest taking a look at [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) instead. that might be able to setup a better pipeline.

Comment: Ok ty, I will try to code, I will come back to you